# Android implementing more fetch data when list arrive to end only works once

Tags: android

I'm trying to implementing get more data from server or database when recyclerview arrive to end list, but my code only works once, and i want to work each finish rows on recyclerview

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (dy > 0) {
            visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisibleItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (loading) {
                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    loading = false;
                    Log.e("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                    if (loadMoreListener != null) {
                        loadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this [EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener](https://github.com/MrOnyszko/it-ebooks.info/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/gratitude/it_ebooks/common/helpers/EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java)

You need to introduce class variable:

```
private EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener endlessRecyclerOnScrollListener;
```

then create new object and pass to it your linear layout manager

```
    endlessRecyclerOnScrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(manager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            // load more request
        }
    };
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(endlessRecyclerOnScrollListener);
```

At the end call reset method in onResume like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    endlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.reset(0, true);
}
```

Everything is in my old [project](https://github.com/MrOnyszko/it-ebooks.info/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/gratitude/it_ebooks/application/activities/SearchActivity.java). I think it will be helpful.

Comment: Show how you add new items to the list.